# Add drawing tools to ui.Panel in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to add Map.Drawing tools to a ui.Panel.
[image]

But since its a Map element, only a ui.Element can be add to a Panel.
This is my script link https://code.earthengine.google.com/7150d049e4579ca199fc73fcef60b6a2

```
var panel = ui.Panel({
  style: {width: '323px', height:"100vh", position:'top-right'}
});
var text = ui.Label({
  value: 'Add Drawing Tools to Panel',
  style: {'color':'red',fontSize: '22px'}
});
panel.add(text)

//Remove the  Drawing Tools from Map()
var drawingTools = Map.drawingTools();
Map.remove(drawingTools)

// Panel with drawing Tools in it
var ui_drawingTools = ui.Map.DrawingTools()
panel.add(ui_drawingTools)
Map.add(panel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing tools aren't a proper widget and cannot be put in a container.  They have to appear on the map directly.

Comment: Thank you Noel,  You're right. After doing some research found how to make a custom button and call the ui.Map.DrawingTools elements with that :) <3

Comment: I wonder why google doesn't lets you do that :/